# Cambiar un campo md5 por UUID

Tags: php, md5, uuid

Colegas, tengo una duda.

Actualmente en mi código almaceno una variable en la base de datos llamado "voucher" en md5 que se genera a partir del momento de la creación tomando como datos dia, mes, año, hora, minuto, segundo, sin embargo me gustaría que ahora el valor fuese un UUID aleatorio.

¿Cómo podría cambiarlo?

Soy muy nuevo en esto de PHP

El código actual es este:

```
$voucher=md5(date('ymdhms').rand());

$sql = "INSERT INTO voucher (voucher,days) VALUES ('$voucher','$days')";
                        if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                            echo "Error al crear voucher";
                        } else {
                        echo "se ha creado el voucher: ".$voucher." de ".$days." d&iacute;as vip";
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From voucher ORDER BY voucherID")){
```

Encontre un artículo para generar UUID.

```
<?php

function gen_uuid() {
 $uuid = array(
  'time_low'  => 0,
  'time_mid'  => 0,
  'time_hi'  => 0,
  'clock_seq_hi' => 0,
  'clock_seq_low' => 0,
  'node'   => array()
 );

 $uuid['time_low'] = mt_Rand(0, 0xffff) + (mt_Rand(0, 0xffff) << 16);
 $uuid['time_mid'] = mt_Rand(0, 0xffff);
 $uuid['time_hi'] = (4 << 12) | (mt_Rand(0, 0x1000));
 $uuid['clock_seq_hi'] = (1 << 7) | (mt_Rand(0, 128));
 $uuid['clock_seq_low'] = mt_Rand(0, 255);

 for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
  $uuid['node'][$i] = mt_Rand(0, 255);
 }

 $uuid = sprintf('%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x',
  $uuid['time_low'],
  $uuid['time_mid'],
  $uuid['time_hi'],
  $uuid['clock_seq_hi'],
  $uuid['clock_seq_low'],
  $uuid['node'][0],
  $uuid['node'][1],
  $uuid['node'][2],
  $uuid['node'][3],
  $uuid['node'][4],
  $uuid['node'][5]
 );

 return $uuid;
}

?>
```

Cómo podría integrarlo?

Intente poner ese código y cambiar la variable de $voucher a $uuid, pero no genero nada, creo me falto llamar a la función pero no se como llamarla, lei una documentación de PHP pero no me queda claro como lo podría hacer

Edición, código completo

```
<?php   
$thefile="logminpanel.php";
require_once("init.php");

//comprobamos que se haya logueado e usuario
if (!$is_admin) {
  @header("Location:logmin.php");
  exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=logmin.php">');
}

//optenemos la opcion a ejecutar
@$action = $_GET['action'];

if (!$can_vip){
  echo'
    <style type="text/css">
      .vipbbcodebuton{display:none;padding:none;}
    </style>
  ';
}

if (isset($_GET['v']) && is_numeric ($_GET['v'])){
  $id = $_GET['v'];
}

switch ($action) {
    case 'new':
                include ("header.php");
                echo '<div><form method=post action=new.php charset="UTF-8" style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;background: none;border: none;">';
                echo'<h4>Ttulo: <input name=Titulo type=text></input></h4><br>';
        echo '<ul class="tabs">';
        for ($n=1;$n<=6;$n++){
                      echo '<li><div href="#tab'.$n.'"><b id="TTab'.$n.'" style="opacity: 0.5;">Desactivado</b></div></li>';
                }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<div class="tab_container" style="padding: 7px;">';
                for ($n=1;$n<=6;$n++){
                echo '<div id="tab'.$n.'" class="tab_content" style="border: none;">Pestaña '.$n.': <input name=Mname'.$n.' type=text onchange="TTab(\'TTab'.$n.'\', this.value)" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();"></input><br />
                <div id="Mirror'.$n.'" onmouseover="BBhover(\'Mirror'.$n.'\')"><textarea id="TMirror'.$n.'" name="Mirror'.$n.'" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea></div></div>';
                }
        if ($can_vip) {
                    echo'<br><label style="width: 100px;padding-left:20px;"><strong>Tipo de paste:</strong></label>
                        <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
                            <option value="0">P&uacute;blico</option>
                            <option value="1">Vip</option>
                        </select>';
                }
                if ($use_password) echo '<br /><label style="width: 100px;padding-left:20px;"><strong>Contrase&ntilde;a:</strong></label><input name=pass type=text value=""></input>';
                echo '<input name="nc" type=hidden value="'.getNonce().'"></input>';
                echo '<br /><center><input type=submit Value="Crear Nuevo"></div></center></form></div>';
                break;
        case 'config':
                include ("header.php");
                    echo '
                        <form method=post action=options-save.php charset="UTF-8">
                        <h2>Datos de Admin</h2>
                        <label><strong>Usuario Admin:</strong></label> <input name=user type=text value="'.$adminuser.'"></input><br />
                        <label><strong>Nuevo Password:</strong></label> <input name=pass type=password></input><br />
                        <label><strong>Confirmar:</strong></label> <input name=passc type=password></input><br />
                        <label><strong>Auth Key:</strong></label><input name=key type=text value="'.$keylogmin.'"></input><br />
                        <br />
                        <h2>Datos del sitio</h2>
                        <label><strong>Nombre:</strong></label> <input name=name type=text value="'.$webname.'"></input><br />
                        <label><strong>Descripci&oacute;n:</strong></label> <input name=desc type=text value="'.$webdescription.'"></input><br />
                        <h2>Publicidad</h2>
                        <strong>Publicidad Arriba:</strong><br />
                        <textarea id="arriba" name="arriba" cols="60" rows="10">'.file_get_contents('arriba.txt').'</textarea><br />
                        <strong>Publicidad Abajo:</strong><br />
                        <textarea id="abajo" name="abajo" cols="60" rows="10">'.file_get_contents('abajo.txt').'</textarea><br />';
            if ($hidelist){
              echo '<strong>Publicidad Inicio (en lugar del listado):</strong><br />
                        <textarea id="home" name="home" cols="60" rows="10">'.file_get_contents('home.txt').'</textarea><br />';
            }
                        echo '<h2>M&oacute;dulos</h2>
                        <label><strong>Registro de usuarios:</strong></label> <select name="register" id="register">';
                        if ($can_register){
                            echo '
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>';
                        }
            echo '</select><br />
                        <label><strong>Confirmación de e-mail:</strong></label> <select name="mailcheck" id="mailcheck">';
                        if ($mailcheck){
                            echo '
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select><br />
                        <label><strong>Usuarios VIP:</strong></label> <select name="vip" id="vip">';
                        if ($can_vip){
                            echo '
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>';
                        }
            echo '</select><br />
                        <label><strong>Modo de urls:</strong></label> <select name="urlmode" id="urlmode">';
                        if ($uri_mode == 2){
                            echo '
                            <option value="2">Modo Compatibilidad (?v=123 -> ?v=abc)</option>
                            <option value="1">Modo Alfabético (?v=abc)</option>
              <option value="0">Modo Numérico (?v=123)</option>';
                        }else if ($uri_mode){
              echo '
                            <option value="1">Modo Alfabético (?v=abc)</option>
              <option value="0">Modo Numérico (?v=123)</option>
              <option value="2">Modo Compatibilidad (?v=123 -> ?v=abc)</option>';
                        } else {
              echo '
              <option value="0">Modo Numérico (?v=123)</option>
              <option value="1">Modo Alfabético (?v=abc)</option>
              <option value="2">Modo Compatibilidad (?v=123 -> ?v=abc)</option>';
                        }
            echo '</select><br />
                        <label><strong>Ocultar listado en inicio:</strong></label> <select name="hidelist" id="hidelist">';
                        if ($hidelist){
              echo '
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>';
                        } else {
              echo '
              <option value="false">Desactivado</option>
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select><br />
                        <label><strong>Contrase&ntilde;a en paste:</strong></label> <select name="passw" id="passw">';
                        if ($use_password){
                            echo '
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select><br />
                        <label><strong>Captcha en paste:</strong></label> <select name="captcha" id="captcha">';
                        if ($use_captcha){
                            echo '
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '
                            <option value="false">Desactivado</option>
                            <option value="true">Activado</option>';
                        }
            echo '</select><br />';
            if ($use_captcha){
                        echo '
                <h2>ReCaptcha</h2>
                            <label><strong>Clave del sitio:</strong></label> <input name=public type=text value="'.$publickey.'"></input><br />
                            <label><strong>Clave secreta:</strong></label> <input name=private type=text value="'.$privatekey.'"></input><br />
                            Nota: Puedes obtener tus claves de recaptcha desde <a href="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/">aqu&iacute;</a>.
                            ';
            }
            echo '<input name="nc" type=hidden value="'.getNonce().'"></input>';
                        echo '<br /><br /><input type=submit Value="Guardar todo"></form>';
                break;
        case 'edit':
                  include ("header.php");
          if (!isset($id)) { exit('Error: parámetro faltante'); }
                  $pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste WHERE pasteID=".$id);
                  $fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc();
                if (isset($fila['Titulo'])) {
                    echo '<div><form method=post action=edit.php charset="UTF-8" style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;background: none;border: none;">
                    <input type=hidden name=v value="'.$id.'">';
                    echo '<h4>Título: <input name=Titulo type=text value="'.$fila['Titulo'].'"></input></h4><br>';
          echo '<ul class="tabs">';
          for ($n=1;$n<=6;$n++){
            if ($fila["Mname$n"]==''){
              echo '<li><div href="#tab'.$n.'"><b id="TTab'.$n.'" style="opacity: 0.5;">Desactivado</b></div></li>';
            } else{
              echo '<li><div href="#tab'.$n.'"><b id="TTab'.$n.'" style="opacity: 1;">'.$fila["Mname$n"].'</b></div></li>';
            }
          }
          echo '</ul>';
          echo '<div class="tab_container" style="padding: 7px;">';
                    for ($n=1;$n<=6;$n++){
                        echo '<div id="tab'.$n.'" class="tab_content" style="border: none;">Pestaña '.$n.': <input name=Mname'.$n.' type=text value="'.$fila["Mname$n"].'" onchange="TTab(\'TTab'.$n.'\', this.value)" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();"></input><br />
                        <div id="Mirror'.$n.'" onmouseover="BBhover(\'Mirror'.$n.'\')"><textarea id="TMirror'.$n.'" name="Mirror'.$n.'" cols="60" rows="20">'.$fila["Mirror$n"].'</textarea><br /></div></div>';
                    }
          if ($can_vip) {
            echo '<br /><label style="width: 100px;padding-left:20px;"><strong>Tipo de paste:</strong></label>
            <select name="tipo" id="tipo">';
            if ($fila['vip']){
              echo '
              <option value="1">Vip</option>
              <option value="0">P&uacute;blico</option>';
            }else{
              echo '
              <option value="0">P&uacute;blico</option>
              <option value="1">Vip</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
          }
          if ($use_password) echo '<br /><label style="width: 100px;padding-left:20px;"><strong>Contrase&ntilde;a:</strong></label><input name=pass type=text value="'.$fila['pass'].'"></input>';
            echo '<input name="nc" type=hidden value="'.getNonce().'"></input>';
            echo '<br /><center><input type=submit Value="Aplicar cambios"></div></form></div></center>';
                }else{
                    echo "<center><strong>Error: El id \"".$id."\" no existe</strong>";
                }
                break;
          case 'solve':
            if (!isset($id)) { exit('Error: parmetro faltante'); }
            if (!(isset($_GET['nc']) && checkNonce($_GET['nc'])))
            exit('Nonce inválido o expirado.');
            if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query("UPDATE paste SET reported=0, Mesrep='' WHERE pasteID='$id'")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                @header("Location:logminpanel.php");
                exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=logminpanel.php">');
                break;
          case 'delete':
                if (!isset($id)) { exit('Error: parámetro faltante'); }
                if (!(isset($_GET['nc']) && checkNonce($_GET['nc'])))
            exit('Nonce inválido o expirado.');
          if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM paste WHERE pasteID='$id'")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                @header("Location:logminpanel.php");
                exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=logminpanel.php">');
                break;
          case 'del':
                if (!isset($id)) { exit('Error: parámetro faltante'); }
                if (!(isset($_GET['nc']) && checkNonce($_GET['nc'])))
            exit('Nonce inválido o expirado.');
          if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM paste WHERE pasteID='$id'")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                @header("Location:logminpanel.php?action=showall&p=".@$_GET['p']."&s=".@$_GET['s']."&filter=".@$_GET['filter']);
                exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=logminpanel.php?action=showall'.@$_GET['p'].'&s='.@$_GET['s'].'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>');
                break;
        case 'showall':
                include ("header.php");
                echo '<center>';
                require_once("pagination.php");
                @$s=preparestr(urldecode ($_GET['s']));
                if (@$_GET['filter']=='all'){
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                    echo "<h3>Todos los Pastes:</h3>";
                    $searchat='all';
                } elseif (@$_GET['filter']=='Searchall'){
                    echo "<h3>Todos los Pastes: '".$s."':</h3>";
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste WHERE Titulo LIKE '%$s%' ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                    $searchat='all';
                } elseif (@$_GET['filter']=='Search'){
                    echo "<h3>Mis Pastes: '".$s."':</h3>";
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste WHERE Titulo LIKE '%$s%' AND user_id = 0 OR user_id IS NUll ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                    $searchat='';
                }else {
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste WHERE user_id = 0 OR user_id IS NUll ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                    echo "<h3>Mis Pastes:</h3>";
                    $searchat='';
                }
                echo "<strong><a href=logminpanel.php?action=showall>Mis Pastes</a> | <a href=logminpanel.php?action=showall&filter=all>Mostrar Todos</a></strong>";
                echo '<strong><table><tr><td colspan=5>

                    <form method="get" class="searchform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="hidden" value="showall" name="action">
                            Buscar: &nbsp; <input type="text" value="'.@$s.'" name="s" style="max-width: 220px;"><button type="submit" name="filter" value="Search'.$searchat.'"></button>

                        </fieldset>
                    </form></td><tr><td>Titulo</td><td colspan=2>Opciones</td>';
        if ($uri_mode){
          $func = 'b10tobstr';
        } else {
          $func = 'doNoThing';
        }
                while($fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo "</tr><td><a href=.?v=".$func($fila['pasteID']).">".$fila['Titulo']. "</a></td><td><a href=logminpanel.php?action=edit&v=".$fila['pasteID'].">Editar</a></td><td><a href=?action=del&v=".$fila['pasteID']."&p=".$pagina."&s=".@$s."&filter=".@$_GET['filter']."&nc=".getNonce().">Eliminar</a></td><tr>";
                }
                echo "</tr></table>";
        $ant=$pagina-1;
        $sig=$pagina+1;
        if (isset($_GET['p']) && $pagina>'1') {
          echo '<p><br /><a href=?p='.$ant.'&action=showall&s='.@$s.'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>&#60;&#60;Anterior</a>';
          $inicio = ($pagina * 10);
          if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",1")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
          $fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc();
          if (isset($fila['Titulo'])){
            echo'   |  <a href=?p='.$sig.'&action=showall&s='.@$s.'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>Siguiente&#62&#62</a></p>';
          }
                 } else {
          $inicio = ($pagina * 10);
          if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",1")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
          $fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc();
          if (isset($fila['Titulo'])){
            echo'<a href=?p='.$sig.'&action=showall&s='.@$s.'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>Siguiente&#62&#62</a></p>';
          }
                }
                break;
        case 'ban':
                if (isset($_GET['uid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uid'])){
                  if (!(isset($_GET['nc']) && checkNonce($_GET['nc'])))
            exit('Nonce inválido o expirado.');
          $Uid=$_GET['uid'];
          if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET banned=1 WHERE userID='$Uid'")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                }
                @header("Location:logminpanel.php?action=users");
                exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=logminpanel.php?action=users">');
                break;
        case 'activate':
        if (isset($_GET['uid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uid'])){
          if (!(isset($_GET['nc']) && checkNonce($_GET['nc'])))
            exit('Nonce inválido o expirado.');
          $Uid=$_GET['uid'];
          if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET banned=0 WHERE userID='$Uid'")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          }
                }
                @header("Location:logminpanel.php?action=users");
                exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=logminpanel.php?action=users">');
                break;
        case 'loginas':
        if (isset($_GET['uid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uid'])){
          if (!(isset($_GET['nc']) && checkNonce($_GET['nc'])))
            exit('Nonce inválido o expirado.');
          $Uid=$_GET['uid'];
          if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from user WHERE  userID='$Uid'")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
          } else {
            $user = $pedir->fetch_assoc();
                    setcookie('muser', $user['userID'], time()+3600);
                    setcookie('msession',$user['pass'],time()+3600);
                    setcookie('logminpaste', '', time()-10);
                    @header("Location:userpanel.php");
                    exit('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=userpanel.php">');
          }
                }
                break;
        Case 'users':
                include ("header.php");
                echo '<center>';
                require ("pagination.php");
                @$filter=$_GET['filter'];
                switch ($filter){
                    case 'inactive':
                        if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From user WHERE banned=1 ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
              echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
            }
                    break;
                    case 'active':
                        if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From user WHERE banned!=1 ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
              echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
            }
                    break;
                    case 'Search':
                        @$s=preparestr(urldecode ($_GET['s']));
                        if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From user WHERE user LIKE '%$s%' ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
              echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
            }
                    break;
                    default:
                        if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From user ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",10")){
              echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
              echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
              echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
              exit;
            }
                    break;
                }
                echo "<strong><table><tr><h3>Todos los usuarios:</h3>";
                echo "<strong><a href=logminpanel.php?action=users>Mostar todos</a> | <a href=logminpanel.php?action=users&filter=inactive>Mostrar No-activos</a> | <a href=logminpanel.php?action=users&filter=active>Mostrar Activos</a></strong> | <a href=logminpanel.php?action=voucher>Cupones premium</a></strong>";
                echo '<table><tr><td colspan=5>
                    <form method="get" class="searchform" action="logminpanel.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="hidden" value="users" name="action">
                            Buscar: &nbsp; <input type="text" value="" name="s" style="max-width: 220px;"><button type="submit" name="filter" value="Search"></button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form></td>
                <tr><td>Nombre de usuario</td><td>Tipo</td><td colspan=3>Opciones</td>';
                while($fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo "</tr><tr><td>".$fila['user'].'</td>';
                 if ($fila['vip']){
                       echo "<td>Vip</td>";
                 } else {
                       echo "<td>Free</td>";
                 }
                 if ($fila['banned']){
                       echo "<td><a href=logminpanel.php?action=activate&uid=".$fila['userID']."&nc=".getNonce().">Activar Usuario</a></td>";
                 } else {
                       echo "<td><a href=logminpanel.php?action=ban&uid=".$fila['userID']."&nc=".getNonce().">Desactivar Usuario</a></td>";
                 }
                 echo "<td><a href=logminpanel.php?action=loginas&uid=".$fila['userID']."&nc=".getNonce().">Logear como ".$fila['user']."</a></td>";
                }
                echo "</tr></table>";
                $ant=$pagina-1;
              $sig=$pagina+1;
        if (isset($_GET['p']) && $pagina>'1') {
                  echo '<p><br /><a href=?p='.$ant.'&action=users&s='.@$s.'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>&#60;&#60;Anterior</a>';
          $inicio = ($pagina * 10);
          if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",1")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
            echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
            echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
            exit;
          }
          $fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc();
                    if (isset($fila['Titulo'])){
                        echo'   |  <a href=?p='.$sig.'&action=users&s='.@$s.'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>Siguiente&#62&#62</a></p>';
                    }
                } else {
                    $inicio = ($pagina * 10);
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From paste ORDER BY pasteID DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",1")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
            echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
            echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
            exit;
          }
                    $fila = $pedir->fetch_assoc();
                    if (isset($fila['Titulo'])){
                        echo'<a href=?p='.$sig.'&action=users&s='.@$s.'&filter='.@$_GET['filter'].'>Siguiente&#62&#62</a></p>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</center>';
                break;
        case 'voucher':
                include ("header.php");
                echo '<center>';
                if ($can_vip) {
                    echo '
                    <h3>Crear Voucher Vip</h3>
                    <form method=post>
                        Cantidad de d&iacute;as vip: &nbsp; <input type=text name=days></input><br />
                        <input type=submit Value="Crear Voucher">
                    </form>';
                    @$days=$_POST['days'];
                    if (is_numeric (@$days)){
                        $voucher = gen_uuid();
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO voucher (voucher,days) VALUES ('$uuid','$days')";
                        if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                            echo "Error al crear voucher";
                        } else {
                        echo "se ha creado el voucher: ".$uuid." de ".$days." d&iacute;as vip";
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$pedir = $mysqli->query("Select * From voucher ORDER BY voucherID")){
            echo 'Fallo al consultar la base de datos.<br>';
            echo 'Errno: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->errno).'<br>';
            echo 'Error: ' . addslashes ($mysqli->error).'<br>';
            exit;
          }
```

Comment: elimine mi respuesta porque cuando la formule no tenia toda la informacion que acabas de actualizar, es muy importante siempre proporcionar el codigo completo para hacer una pregunta ya que a veces el error no suele estar donde nosotros pensamos y puede chocar con otras funciones.

Comment: @Ruben Entiendo, espero alguien me pueda hechar la mano, gracias.

Comment: Con la función 'uniqid' echo uniquid()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mejor usa la funcion oficial de PHP para generar un GUID

Crea la funcion en un nuevo PHP por ejemplo **guid.php**, lo guardas en la misma ruta.

```
<?php
function GUID()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
    {
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
    }

    return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
}
?>
```

Agregas el archivo guid.php y llamas a la funcion para que te del nuevo GUID.

```
require_once("guid.php");
$voucher = GUID();
```

Si quieres puedes incluir la funcion en el mismo archivo.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.com-create-guid.php